# Rename the Closed File

Tags: c#, .net

When I close the C# window, I hope to append the timestamp to the filename. However, when I run the following codes, I got such error:

> 'System.NotSupportedException'

and

> "The given path's format is not
>   supported.".

Is there any method to modify the parameters?

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw_bea.Close();
    String file_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt").ToString();
    System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tmp_bea.txt", @"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tmp_bea"+file_Time+".txt");
}
```

Comment: You have to remove those colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some have commented, the proximate problem are the colons in your filename.

In general, if you want to ensure that a filename doesn't contain illegal characters, you can do something like

```
for (char c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    filename=filename.Replace(c, '_');
```

Comment: While the OP's issue is probably solved more easily by simply avoiding the `:` character in the first place, it's very useful to know about `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`. (I hadn't heard of it before.) So thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

The following reserved characters are not allowed in Windows filenames:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

Your filename includes '**:**' due to the time format you've selected.

Refer to [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces at Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) for further details.  Make sure to check out that article, as it lists more than I've included here, such as ASCII NUL and so on.

Personally, when I include date or time in filenames, I remove any separators and put everything into military time.  So, 2:03 PM would be 1403, 5:20 AM would be 0520.  Right now it would be 08012016_1217 (8/1/2016 12:17 PM).  As you can see, I separate blocks of "information" by an underscore, as is the case here with date and time.  It has been pretty easy to work with thus far.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can not use reserved characters due to Windows Operating System restrictions. This is how I do it:

```
string MyFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM_HH-mm-ss");
```